# How irreducibility of scheme Y is used in the following statement?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume X,Y,Z are schemes.
Here are the definitions adopted(from the rising sea):

> A rational map $\pi$ from $X$ to $Y$,denoted $\pi:X\dashrightarrow Y$,is a morphism on a dense open set,with the equivalence relation ($\alpha :X\rightarrow  Y)\sim (\beta:X\rightarrow Y)$if there is a dense open $Z\subseteq X\cap Y$ on which $\alpha,\beta$ agree.
>
> A rational map $\pi:X\dashrightarrow Y$ is dominant if for some(hence every) representation $U\rightarrow Y$,the image is dense in $Y$.

following the definition in the book is a statement:

> “you can compose a dominant map $\pi:X\dashrightarrow Y$ from an irreducible scheme $X$ to an irreducible scheme $Y$ with a rational map $ρ:Y\dashrightarrow Z$ and the composition ρπ is dominant if ρ is.”

what I have done:

To define a rational map $X\dashrightarrow Z$,pick up representations ($U\rightarrow Y)$for $π$ and ($V\rightarrow Z$) for ρ respectively.$\pi(U)$ must intersects $V$ because $\pi$ is dominant and $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)\cap V)$ is open dense(irreducibility of $X$).restrict ($U\rightarrow Y$) to this smaller dense open subset and compose it with ($V\rightarrow Z$) yields a representation for the desired rational map.

Now suppose ρ is also dominant.For notation convenience,set $\pi(U)\subseteq V$ and I denote representations $U\rightarrow Y,V\rightarrow Z$ of rational maps ρ,π by “themselves”,namely ρ,π.given a open set $W$ of $Z$,I will prove $W$ intersects $ρπ(U)$:since ρ is dominant,$W\cap ρ(V)\neq \varnothing$,so $ρ^{-1}(W)$ is open and non-empty,hence intersects $\pi(U)$($\pi$ is dominant) from which I can conclude $W\cap ρπ(U)$ is not empty,ρπ is dominant.

So where irreducibility of $Y$ should be used?is this condition really unnecessary?

Any hint plz,thanks.

Comment: This will depend heavily on your definition of dominant. How do you define density of image? For example, consider the map of rings $k[x]/x^2\to k$ inducing a map of schemes. Is this dominant for you?

Comment: @Mohan to define density of image,the topology on Y is the Zariski topology and being dense is in the usual topological sense.

Comment: @Mohan yes,the example is dominant.

Comment: If you use this definition then you might be alright. Usually, dominant means injectivity of rational functions too.

Comment: @Mohan and the schemes mentioned are usually irreducible to make composing such maps possible?I think this might be the reason why Y is also required to be irreducible.